# Sorting numerically result of directory_map()

Tags: php, sorting, codeigniter-3

I am making a simple website using CodeIgniter 3.1.11 in which I use directory_map() to get all the photos contained in a folder.

It is hosted on Debian and the photos are named numerically and I would like them to be returned in the numerical order but instead of having this :

```
 1.jpg
 ...
 9.jpg
 10.jpg
 ...
 19.jpg
 20.jpg
 etc...
```

I have :

```
 1.jpg
 10.jpg
 11.jpg
 ...
 2.jpg
 20.jpg
 21.jpg
 etc...
```

I tried adding a `sort()` in the `directory_map()` function before returning the array, as I saw in many topics :

```
natsort($filedata);
return $filedata;
```

but the `natsort()` most people adviced in several topics doesn't seem to order them in the right way.

So i'm kinda stuck here, I think PHP orders the files this way like strings and not integers but i don't know what to do about it.

All help will be very appriciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try usort()

```php
usort( $filedata, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) return 0;
    if (intval($a) == intval($b)) return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
    return (intval($a) < intval($b)) ? -1 : 1;
});
```